# Improve performance of a Java Program

Tags: java, performance, swing, file-io, profiling

I've made an Applet Search Utility in which I provide a string as input and find that string in the specified file or folder.
I've done with this but I m not happy with its performance.
The process is taking too much time to respond.
I decided to do its profiling to see what is happening and I noticed that the method scanner.hasNextLine() is taking most of the time.
Though this is very important method for my program because I have to read all the lines and find that string, Is there any other way by which I can improve its performance and reduce the execution time

Here is the code where I am using this method ....

```
fw = new FileWriter("filePath", true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for (File file : filenames) {
            if(file.isHidden())
                continue;

                if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
                int cnt = 0;
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    if(!exactMatch)
                    {
                        if(!caseSensitive)
                        {
                            if (line.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                                // System.out.println(line);
                                cnt += StringUtils.countMatches(line.toLowerCase(),
                                        searchString.toLowerCase());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (line.contains(searchString)) {
                                // System.out.println(line);
                                cnt += StringUtils.countMatches(line,
                                        searchString);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

And yes the method toLowerCase() is also taking more time then expected.

---

I have changed my code and now I am using `BufferedReader` in place of `Scanner` as **Alex** and **Nrj** suggested and I found a nice improvement in the performance of my application.
It is now processing in one third time of its earlier version.
Thanks to all that replied.....

Comment: Why on earth are you embedding a file finder in a web page?

Comment: Andrew thanks for your comment but the applet is not embedded on a webpage it is a desktop application.

Comment: So, by 'applet' do you mean a) 'small application', or b) a class that extends `Applet` or `JApplet`?

Comment: It is not a very small application... and yes one of a class in which I initialized applet component extends `Applet`

Comment: In that case, ***don't extend applet.***  Instead have a `main(String[])` method that creates a `JFrame`.  Put the GUI in the frame to display it.

Comment: You can bring `if (!casesensitive) searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();` outside the loop. Same trick for line, so only one inner if-statement remains - without twice line.toLowerCase.

Comment: @JoopEggen it is not possible to eliminate  `if (!casesensitive)` because I need them inside loop because if user select exact match then it will be disable else it will be enabled...   As you seen in any text editor exact match or case insensitive match....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your question I examined code of `Scanner` and I think that your are right. It is not optimized to work with large data. I'd recommend you to use simple `BufferedReader` that wraps `InputStreamReader` that wraps `FileInputStream`:

`BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)))`

then read line-by-line:

`r.readLine()`

If this is not enough for you try to read bulks of  lines and then process them.

Concerning to `toLowerCase()` you can try to use regular expressions instead. The benefit is that you do not have to change the case of line every time. The disadvantage is that in simple cases regular expression works a bit slower than regular string comparison.

Comment: Thanks Alex I'll try BufferedReader and if it works then I'll definitely notify here to all viewers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest redesigning your solution and use something like Lucene to do the search for you. You can index and search files with Lucene much more efficiently, tutorial on how to do it with text files can be found here: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-lucene-to-index-and-search-text-files.html

Answer (score 1):

(Only small optimizations, in response to comment above.)

```
            if(!caseSensitive)
            {
                searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
            }
            while (true) {
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                if(!caseSensitive)
                {
                    line = line.toLowerCase();
                }
                if(!exactMatch)
                {
                    if (line.contains(searchString)) {
                        // System.out.println(line);
                        cnt += StringUtils.countMatches(line,
                                searchString);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using `BufferedReader`
2. Make use of threads. You can search the files in parallel which should reduce the search time.

Comment: You won't get much performance increase from threads because of IO overhead.

Comment: @Max Shouldn't high IO allows more threads to get a chance to run ? Also with all the multi cores now days, threading should increase the throughput here.. Correct me if this is not the case...

Comment: It's very hard to estimate something with multiple threads doing IO, as there are many factors involved. Problem is, when you are scanning files for text, you are basically using 100% of IO to read files, it's the overhead of the application. But for those 100% of IO, only some minor percent of CPU will be used (because almost no data processing will be done). Using several threads for reading different files would only help if IO could also be parallelized (maybe some kind of RAID array with custom drivers allows that but I'm not sure).

Answer (score -2):

I would not use Java to search the file system for matches of the string. Instead invoke a native algorithm from Java instead. I would invoke grep from Java using something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("grep", "-r", "foo");
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
//Do whatever you prefer with the stream
```

Comment: Please kindly explain why wouldn't you do that with Java?

Comment: The String.contains() algo scans each byte of the String line looking for the first character of the match string. Whenever it finds the first matching char, it will try to match the remainder of the string. At best, it will run in O(n) in linear time and there are better algorithms for String searching. Grep uses a revised Boyer-Moore algo which will search much quicker and it it's native C code so doesn't need to do any dynamic translation.

Comment: You can implement that algorithm in Java, and there already are libraries that succesfully use it. Moreover, if you implement it in Java - then it would be cross-platform and won't depend on external tools. Therefore I disagree with your statement `I would not use Java to search the file system for matches of the string`.